# How to have an inline image with a bullet list?

Tags: html

I haven't found a way to have a bullet list (generated by a loop) side by side with an image

The code is this:

```
<!-- POSTS BY YEAR -->
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% capture current_year %}{{ post.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %}
  {% if current_year != previous_year %}
    {% unless forloop.first %}
      </ul>
    {% endunless %}
    <h2>{{ current_year }}</h2>
    <ul>
    {% assign previous_year = current_year %}
  {% endif %}
  <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">
  {{ post.date | date: "%Y-%m-%d" }} - {{ post.title }}
  </a></li>

  {% if forloop.last %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


</div>

    <img style='vertical-align:right;width:304px;height:228px;' src='/assets/archiveSM.jpg'>
</p>
```

And the result looks like  [this (desired outcome marked in the screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB5wO.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can float the image as @jbe said on his answer, but that will be a non responsive solution. Use `display: flex` instead on the top container.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul{
  flex: 1;
}

/* Makeup */ .container{background-color: #f5f5f5;padding: 1rem;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
  </ul>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB5wO.jpg" width=304 height=228>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

place the `img` above the list and use `float: right`

```css
    .img {
      float: right;
    }
```

```html
    <img class="img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400" alt="">
    
    <ul>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
```